# Python: Algorithm of clustermap Seaborn

Tags: python, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, seaborn

I want to understand the working (algorithm) of clustermap of Seaborn in Python. For instance, what parameters/features does clustermap consider when forming clusters. I tried to google it but couldn't find any description/explanation of clustermap algorithm or working mechanism. The official page (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) only describe "how to use it". Could any point me any literature or website where clustermap algorithm of seaborn is explained? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: People have started voting down without giving any reason.

Comment: Requests like *"Could any[one] point me [to] any literature or website [...]"* are considered off-topic on stackoverflow. See point 4 in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Seaborn is open source. Did you check the source code?

Answer (score 1):

They use **hierarchical clustering**.

This is a widely known technique, explained in any decent textbook on data mining. In fact, it may be worth going back to old textbooks such as Anderberg in the 1970s, as they are likely to devote more time on these methods than today's books, which tend to waste a lot of pages on map reduce etc.